# Re-Scaling google map view on android?

Tags: android

ive gotten google map api v2 working but when i select the app the map is the fullscreen.
How do i make it smaller? particularly to a set width and height and screen location (top left corner)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use layouts and the parameters in your XML layout file to change sizes, positions, etc. For example, from google's sample code for showing 4 copies of the map in 4 quadrants of the screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map_container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      map:cameraTargetLat="40.72"
      map:cameraTargetLng="-74.00"
      map:cameraZoom="8"/>
    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      map:cameraTargetLat="51.51"
      map:cameraTargetLng="-0.12"
      map:cameraZoom="8"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map3"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      map:cameraTargetLat="48.85"
      map:cameraTargetLng="2.35"
      map:cameraZoom="8"/>
    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map4"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      map:cameraTargetLat="35.69"
      map:cameraTargetLng="139.69"
      map:cameraZoom="8"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```